# How can I fall back to the default behaviour when using mui datagrid rendereditcell

Tags: material-ui

I'm using MUI 5 data-grid (basic, not pro, etc.) and I need a custom renderEditCell function, which I know how to use, but the cell content can be either a plain string or an object. If its an object I want to use a custom editor but if its a plain string I want the user to be able to edit in-place as a normal cell.

So how can I return a value from my renderEditCell function that invokes the default behavour? Can I import the default function and return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GridEditInputCell` component to fall back to the default.

```
renderEditCell: (params) => {
    if (customCondition) {
       return (
           <CustomEditComponent />
       );
    }
    return <GridEditInputCell {...params} />;
 },
```